# Designing a shared-role web apps

Tags: design, architecture, web-services, roles, active-directory

I have several Django services which all have their own login portal, and colleagues have a user/pass for each portal (if we've given them permission). We'd like to unite all of these portals and there are a couple different options:

1) Just create a new service that is one giant consolidated tool, and get rid of the old ones. Might be a headache integrating this with the databases and other functionality of each service (both technically, and organizational overhead since teams will have to be in sync).

2) Keep each service (and its login portal) separate, and have some login layer in front.

We want to avoid reinventing the wheel if an RBAC system is to be involved. We also want to keep things as simple as possible. The only major requirement is to have one login per user (across all admin tools), and to customize permissions for each user. Permissions goals, in decreasing order of importance, are:

- Access on a per-service level
- Access on a per-feature
  (i.e. individual settings within a service) level
- Integration with something like Azure Active
  Directory

Are there any tools that exist that would allow us to keep this as simple as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like a BPM business process manager such as jBPM or Websphere process engine and move your admin processes as well defined workflows that integrate with each other.